# Telerik Zip UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, telerik

When try to Unzip file with telerik controls demo:

```
Telerik.WinControls.Zip.Extensions.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(@"Log.zip", "Log", System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access Denied

in any Folder and Path, why? Telerik not answer my question with trial license.

I have try with zip control from net 4.5 but vs 2013 say no ZipFile function on System.IO.Compression

Comment: Try to run Telerik Demo under administration privileges

Comment: Yes, same problem! I'm not that stupid.

Comment: Btw where you have posted on the Telerik forums as I cannot see your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to extract in C:\temp and also move your Log.zip to c:\temp to read it from there.

Also, make sure it is not read only and you can open it.

The method mentioned calls:

```
File.Open(archiveFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

so you can try opening the Log.zip with this API and see if it succeeds.

If this works, then try the following to the path where you want to extract to see if you have permissions to write there:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationDirectoryName)
```